# Possible use of "formal": absence of rigor

Tags: meaning, word-usage

[According to the Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/formal), the word "formal" used as an adjective has, among other definitions, these meanings ([...] are examples or precisions):

> 1. Done in accordance with convention or etiquette; suitable for or constituting an official or important occasion: [...]
> 2. Officially sanctioned or recognized: [...]
> 3. Of or concerned with outward form or appearance as distinct from content: [...]

The definitions 1. and 2. may have an opposite meaning to 3. in some contexts. More precisely, in mathematics, one often uses the adjective "formal" to express the absence of rigor (content) and emphasize on the idea that what is exposed is heuristic and makes sense in terms of symbols (outward form/appearance). There is a question about the use of the word "formal" in mathematics on the [mathematics community](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53969/what-does-formal-mean).

However, it seems that "formal" and the derived adverb "formally" are generally used to express rigor, at least in common language (this is my observation and there is a high chance that it is biased since I am not a native speaker of English and I do not live in an English-speaking country). Searching for questions containing the word "formal" on this community mostly yields posts were the meaning is 1. Even the description of the tag [formality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formality) refers to the meaning 1.

When writing in English, if I want to make one understand that I do not focus on rigor, I use the words "informal" and "informally", to emphasize the fact that it bears (motivational) informations and not rigor. This does not quite satisfy me, as I am not sure if my worries about the use and possible ambiguity of "formal" are founded on existing subtleties of its meaning and use.

Is the word "formal" really often used to mean "without rigor" as used in mathematics papers and books? Or is it a particularity of mathematical/scientific usage of the word?

Comment: First, don't use the ELU tag system for any description of language; it's hopelessly confused and useless. Second, _formal_ as an abstract term has since Aristotle been in opposition to _material_, and refers to symbolic rather than physical properties, events, objects, and reality. So all mathematics is formal, since mathematics is entirely abstract. Third, as for _rigor_, that refers to more-or-less clear logical development in ordinary language, but in mathematics it refers to adherence to particular styles of development in a proof.

Comment: @JohnLawler Either I don't understand your comment, or it reinforces my idea: the usage of the word "formal", especially in mathematics, is ambiguous. I agree that mathematics is formal in the sense you describe, but the word itself has particular meanings within the field, meanings that are sometimes antagonist. My question here is to understand if it is specific to mathematics or if it is sometimes used to intend something not rigorous in any other situation.

Comment: I realize there's a school of metamathematics that's given a "formal" cognomen, just as there are schools of logic and other philosophies -- even semantics -- that are called "formal". That's just nomenclature. And there's nothing like mathematical rigor outside mathematical abstraction; what passes for "rigorous thinking" in science or daily life is like kindergarten compared to (say) Wiles's proof of the Taniyama-Shimura conjecture.

Comment: @JohnLawler Ok, I think I see what you mean. Somehow, my question does not make sense because the word "rigor" as I use it only refers to the mathematical conception of rigor and therefore cannot be extended to any other usage. In some sense, you answered my question. However, are you familiar with this particular usage of "formal" in mathematics, usage that seems contradictory to the very definition of "formal" (since being mathematically rigorous may be seen as being respectful of mathematical conventions/axioms and logical conception).

Comment: In the last analysis, "rigor" is a form of gradual group decision among specialist mathematicians that the author **could**, if necessary, construct a full "formal" proof. Not that anybody ever does, at least since Whitehead and Russell. Rather like what's discussed in Davis and Hersh's ["The Ideal Mathematician"](http://users-cs.au.dk/danvy/the-ideal-mathematician.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler The philosophical discussion on what is rigor is interesting but misses the point, imho. Rigor is a concept that most young students in mathematics understand quickly. Even if they are far from being specialists, they know what is considered rigorous and what is not. For example, a proof of Euler's identity with real Taylor series is formal, in the sense "not rigorous", as it doesn't even define what the exponential of a complex number is, which is all the point. The only thing one should check for complete rigor is that "definitions are well-defined" in the initial formalism.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds this very hard to follow? Who thinks that broadly speaking, 'formal' and 'rigourous' mean the same and even if they didn't, could never be the opposites I seem to be reading about here?
 
Where did I go wrong, please Guys?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I am not a native speaker and in my language, "formal" is translated in a word that can be used to mean "rigorous" or, somehow, the opposite. More particularly, in my field (mathematics), in English and in my language, the word is used to mean either one or the opposite. From the comments here, I understand that my interpretation was wrong in a broad sense and, even in the particular case of mathematical terminology, can be considered as meaningless.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Also note that, in mathematics, it is very clear how the word "formal" can mean "rigorous" or the opposite, at least for people used to read university-level mathematics: some people say "formally, we obtain (...)", which can be understood as "without taking care of the rigor, we obtain" with the underlying assumption that we can make the argument rigorous. On the other hand, some people use "More formally, we get (...)" to mean "in following the conventions regarding rigor more precautiously, we get (...)".

Comment: Well, thanks and I thought your original question was about English, and mentioned special uses in maths only as a sideline and the rule them out…